# Posting more to a solved question

Tags: discussion, etiquette

When a user asks an extension of a question that was already marked, is it fair to ask him to post his extension as a new question (or) should the extension be answered since it is related to the original question?

I was not sure if I was doing the right thing asking the user to post his extension as a new question, please clarify

Question in context : [Font Size of Tabs and its content](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/25742/font-size-of-tabs-and-its-content)

Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If the question was marked as an answer already, I think it should be a new question. If looking at it from a futuristic POV, you might see answers, that are marked as correct, but actually do not answer the question.

Comment: i do have a easy fix for rounding the corners, i was planning to post it if the user does not want to create a new thread. I was looking for answers and found it after a bit of reading through which made me feel it would be a good to have answer just in case someones looking for the same.